# Regex to match anything until space sequence include + or - simbols on sums

Tags: regex

I have multiline string

https://regex101.com/r/RQP7Kk/3

```
  __    05.01.19     21:16 TD Ølby, Center      diesel                         299,99             10,39  3115,41

      05.01.19                                Rabat                               299,99             -1,92  -575,98

      26.01.19     18:57 TD Ølby, Center      AdBlue                              38,29              5,91   226,39

      26.01.19                                Rabat                               38,29              -3,00  -114,88
```

I trying to extract each field

```
.*(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}) .*(\d{2}\:\d{2}) (.+?) {2,} (.+?) {2,}(-?\d+,\d+).+?(-?\d+,\d+).+?(-?\d+,\d+)
```

but something wrong, which is right syntax?

need to get

```
05.01.19;21:16;TD Ølby, Center;diesel;299,99;10,39;3115,41
05.01.19;Null;Null;Rabat;299,99;-1,92;-575,98
26.01.19,18:57;TD Ølby, Center;AdBlue;38,29;5,91;226,39
26.01.19;Null;Null;Rabat;38,29;-3,00;-114,88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
/^[^\d]* # starting characters
    (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}) # datestamp
    \s+
    (?:  # optional captures
        (\d{2}:\d{2}) # timestamp
        \s+
        ((?:[^\s]+\s)*[^\s]+) # location
        \s+
    )?
    ([^\s]+) # product / Rabat
    \s+
    (-?\d+,\d+) # first number
    \s+
    (-?\d+,\d+) # second number
    \s+
    (-?\d+,\d+) # third number
/gixm
```

Comment: one line please

Comment: you can remove all the comments and whitespace and the x flag and execute it as a one-liner. i would like to leave the answer as is for better readability.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190350/discussion-between-sam-and-dmitrij-holkin).

Comment: add to answer this one for VBA `^[^\d]*(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\s+(?:(\d{2}:\d{2})\s+((?:[^\s]+\s?)+[^\s])\s+)?([^\s]+)\s+(-?\d+,\d+)\s+(-?\d+,\d+)\s+(-?\d+,\d+)`

Answer (score 2):

You can seperate each group by whitespace, and use this regex pattern:

`[_ ]* ([\d\.]+)[ ]+ (([\d\:]+) ([^ ]+ )([^ ]+ )([^ ]+)[ ]+|[ ]+) ([^ ]+)[ ]+ ([^ ]+)[ ]+ ([^ ]+)[ ]+ ([^ ]+)$`

and this substition:

`\1;\3;\4\5\6;\7;\8;\9;\10`

which will leads you to this output:

```
05.01.19;21:16;TD Ølby, Center;diesel;299,99;10,39;3115,41
05.01.19;;;Rabat;299,99;-1,92;-575,98
26.01.19;18:57;TD Ølby, Center;AdBlue;38,29;5,91;226,39
26.01.19;;;Rabat;38,29;-3,00;-114,88
```

The most important part maybe is this, you can use "|" to say "or" in regex.

```
([^ ]+ )([^ ]+ )([^ ]+)[ ]+|[ ]+)
```

See online regex tester here: https://regex101.com/r/EJISOh/4

Comment: Problem is that cant be used substitution, as I don't know how match groups will be on third group

Comment: Yeah, the third group (or the 2nd capturing group exactly)  is not used in my substition. And notice that 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th capturing groups are all in 2nd capturing group. Use optional captures "(?:" like Sam would be more understandable. But they both works.